# How to get live wind from a site in python

Tags: python

Hi I am writing a python script where it takes live wind from a given site where I live, now if I use the following code on the website I get a 'none' value but on the website there is information at the given position.

I tried this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = 'http://www.actuelewind.nl/?stationcode=6308#SpotPage'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'}

def checkwind():
    pagina = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina.content, 'html.parser')
    windsnelheid = soup.find('div', attrs={"id": "spotInfoWindsnelheidMS"})
    print(windsnelheid)
checkwind()
```

Can anyone show me how to get live wind from this website?

Comment: I dont see any `current-wind__speed` anywhere on that page

Comment: I'm sorry, the it should be 'attrs={"class": "spotInfoWindsnelheidMS"}'

Comment: Ah okay, well in that instance `spotInfoWindsnelheidMS` is an id, not a class identifier. Try `soup.find(id="spotInfoWindsnelheidMS")`

Comment: If I do that i get this, `<div class="spotDetailBlockInfo" id="spotInfoWindsnelheidMS"></div>` but there is no information between, how do I solve that

Comment: Yeah I've tried this out myself and I'm getting the same thing, not sure why. Sorry mate

Comment: A little bit more reading implies to me that this data is populated with JavaScript, so BeautifulSoup cannot do this by itself. Another post I found suggested to use Selenium as well as BS

Comment: I tried this already but the phantomJS does not work but is their an other way to get around this problem?